# "The specified bucket does not exist" when upload .json into S3 (localstack)?

Tags: amazon-s3, localstack

I runned a docker container like this:

```
localstack:
   image: localstack/localstack:latest
   network_mode: host
   container_name: localstack
   environment:
     - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=secret
     - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret
     - EDGE_PORT=4566
     - SERVICES=s3
   privileged: true
```

I have to upload json file in root level in my bucket.
When I uploaded file and check it in S3 i see this error than correct information:

**`NoSuchBucket`The specified bucket does not existOI56Y0V8GWFODQ5AUUGPZFV2ERTQQONGJ3RF2PVVFRK6LSFA9U5J**
If I upload another file, for example .jsonl - I haven't this mistake.

What's happend?